# Accumulating rotations for camera

Tags: 3d, mathematics, camera, matrix, quaternion

It seems there are three ways to store a camera's rotation: in angles, view matrix or quaternion. I was using euler angles since when I used a matrix it had a tendency to accumulate rounding errors quickly that threw off everything and quaternions would have the same problem.

The problem I've run into is how do I accumulate the rotation? When the camera is rotated, it's rotated in local space about its local XYZ axes. How would you use the given angles in a rotation to rotate about these arbitrary axes? Usually this operation is done with a matrix but it doesn't make sense to try to extract the new angles out of it.

Or perhaps I should be just storing the rotation in a matrix or quaternion? But can this be done without errors eventually causing problems?

Comment: Your errors came from accumulating rotations, not how they were stored in matrices or quaternions or whatever.  Don't accumulate, rebuild every frame.

Comment: The errors come from storing in matrices/quaternions BECAUSE they aren't being rebuilt every frame. What I'm asking is how to rebuild with the local XYZ axes. Normally one just accumulates the rotation with matrices.

Comment: Here's an answer from stackoverflow.  In brief, you have to maintain all three of your own axes, and each time you rotate around one, you must update the other two.  [Question that isn't really about touch, but is about 3D rotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976714/windows-phone-3d-model-rotation-with-touch/11978082#11978082)...actually, let me recreate that here.

Answer (score 2):

You must maintain each of your three local axes.  When you rotate around one, you must update the other two.

```
class gameclass
{
Vector3 forward = Vector3.UnitZ;    //persistent orientation variables
Vector3 left    = -1 * Vector3.UnitX;
Vector3 up      = Vector3.UnitY

Matrix world = Matrix.Identitiy;

InputClass inputclass;           //something to get your input data

void Update()
{

Vector3 pitch = inputclass.getpitch();          //vertical swipe/stick
forward = Vector3.transform(forward, Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(left, pitch));
up      = Vector3.transform(up, Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(left, pitch));

Vector3 yaw = inputclass.getyaw();              //horizontal swipe/stick
forward = Vector3.transform(forward, Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(up, yaw));
left    = Vector3.transform(left, Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(up, yaw));

forward.Normalize(); left.Normalize(); top.Normalize();  //avoid rounding errors

world = Matrix.CreateWorld(
    postition                     //this isn't defined in my code
    forward,
    up);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to have a view matrix to send to the shader, and your camera's rotation already in it, and it's an ortho-normal matrix, why not use it as your 'storage' device?

Assuming whatever framework you are using has methods for transposing matrices, rotations about arbitrary axis, multiplying a vector by a matrix(transforming), & building a matrix from 2 vectors. Here's some xna code but can be thought of as pseudo code.

```
Vector3 camPosition;
Vector3 camTarget = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);//init to whatever you want. does not need to be unit length
Matrix view = Matrix.Identity;

//these items should be updated each frame before updating camera
float pitchChangeFromLastFrame, yawChangeFromLastFrame;//long names just to clarify meaning
float arcPitchChangeFromLastFrame, arcYawChangeFromLastFrame;
Vector3 pointToArcAbout;//usually the camTarget
Vector3 strafe;
public void CameraUpdate()
{
    Matrix camWorld = Matrix.Transpose(view);

    //pitch camera (tilt)
    camTarget = Vector3.Transform(camTarget - camPosition, Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(camWorld.Right, pitchChangeFromLastFrame)) + camPosition;

    //yaw camera (pan)
    camTarget = Vector3.Transform(camTarget - camPosition, Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(camWorld.Up, yawChangeFromLastFrame)) + camPosition;//often you would use 0,1,0 instead of camWorld.Up

    //strafe camera (track)
    camPosition += strafe;
    camTarget += strafe;

    //arc camera (pitch)
    camPosition = Vector3.Transform(camPosition - pointToArcAbout, Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(camWorld.Right, arcPitchChangeFromLastFrame)) + pointToArcAbout;

    //arc camera (yaw)
    camPosition = Vector3.Transform(camPosition - pointToArcAbout, Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(camWorld.Up, arcYawChangeFromLastFrame)) + pointToArcAbout;

    //rebuild view matrix
    view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(camPosition, camTarget, Vector3.Up);//creates an ortho normal matrix each frame from 2 vectors (camTarget - camPosition, & the up vector)
}
```

Essentially this takes 2 points in space (position & target) and rotates them about each other (using local axes) or moves them together (strafe), then builds a brand new ortho normal matrix each frame from them.